# Change the Attr and do new function not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically what I'm doing is:

1* if button reset clicked, it will empty all the values:

```
$('#reset').click(function(){$('textarea').val('');});
```

2* After submitting the form this function will be executed:

```
function ToDoAfterSubmit()
{
$('#linewhichischeckednowhide').show(); 
$('textarea').attr("disabled", true);
$('#reset').html("Stop");
$('#reset').attr("id", "stop");
$('#stop').click(function(){alert('ok');}); 
}
```

As you can see here in the function i changed the attribute of the button `Reset` and i gave to it a new work to do which is alerting, however when i click on it, the alert will show up, but the values are removed also. How i can do only the alerting i don't want the values to be removed?

Comment: `.click` **adds** an event handler. It does not remove or replace existing ones.

Comment: i already reaplace it here !!  $('#reset').html("Stop");
$('#reset').attr("id", "stop");

Comment: @FelixKling The question that this question has been redirected to is 5 years old and there is a solution that doesn't involve the binding of event handlers. In fact, .bind() and .unbind() are old methods. [As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)  .on() and .off() are not mentioned in that question.

Comment: @zer00ne: feel free to update the answer of the linked question or let me know about a better duplicate.

Comment: @SniperCoder: that is changing the element's content and ID, but not the event handlers bound to it.

Comment: @FelixKling Should I answer in the context of the question there or the context of the question here? My solution for SniperCoder doesn't involve removing event handlers. My solution simplifies his code and in turn resolves his problem.

Comment: if you can write the code for me that would be better